# jboss brms 6.1 install business-central not working

Tags: jboss, business-process-management

I am following the instructions from this 
https://github.com/jbossdemocentral/brms-install-demo provided by Eric D Schabell.
I have followed the exact same steps for option-1 (install on your own machine).
ALso downloaded the following products as instructed

> - EAP installer (jboss-eap-6.4.0-installer.jar)  * BRMS installer
>     (jboss-brms-6.1.0.GA-installer.jar)

Then ran the init.bat from ..\brms-install-demo-master directory.

I get the following output on the console (showing successfull installation )

> Product sources are present...
>
> Product sources are present...
>
> EAP installer running now...
>
> JBoss BRMS installer running now...
>
> - enabling demo accounts role setup in application-roles.properties file...
>
> 1 File(s) copied
>
> - setting up standalone.xml configuration adjustments...
>
> 1 File(s) copied
>
> - setup email task notification users...
>
> C:\tools\brms-install-demo-master\support\userinfo.properties
>   1 File(s) copied
>
> You can now start the JBoss BRMS with C:\tools\brms-install-demo-> master\target\jboss-eap-6.4\bin\standalone.bat
>
> You can open business central in browser at:
>
> localhost:8080/business-central
>
> and login as user: erics and password: jbossbrms1!
>
> JBoss BRMS 6.1 Install Demo Setup Complete.

But when i start the brms product using standalone.bat from

> ..\brms-install-demo-master\target\jboss-eap-6.4\bin

And I hit this path,

> http://localhost:8080/business-central

I get this error

> JBWEB000068: message /business-central 
>    JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available.

Answer (score 0):

There have been some fixes just applied to the init.bat that we are testing here right now:

https://github.com/jbossdemocentral/brms-install-demo

Would you mind testing this and if it works for you then we will apply to the Cool Store demo too.

Note I have added this to the Cool Store project here:

https://github.com/jbossdemocentral/brms-coolstore-demo/issues/39

Comment: I did the git clone again and put back the .jars in the install folder. Re-did the init.bat and then standalone.bat, But I get the same message when i open the 
> localhost:8080/business-central link.

/business-central  : the requested resource is not available.

Comment: I have pasted my server startup logs here 
http://pastebin.com/ifg5Z4MY
It seems to have started successfully...

By the way, the bpms-install-demo project works fine for me and lets me access the business-central webapp just fine. 

its the brms-install-demo that I am having this issue with. 
May be that helps in debugging further..

Answer (score 0):

I tested both the unpatched and patched version and was able to access Business Central. Do you experience any errors in the server logs when and can you verify the server has started fully?

Comment: I have pasted my server startup logs here 
http://pastebin.com/ifg5Z4MY
It seems to have started successfully...

By the way, the bpms-install-demo project works fine for me and lets me access the business-central webapp just fine. 

its the brms-install-demo that I am having this issue with. 
May be that helps in debugging further..